# component.find(...).getElement is not a function within 1 component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I'm trying to enable a button when a field changes in my lightning component but I keep getting the error [component.find(...).getElement is not a function].

this is my component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"  
                access="global">
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning:input aura:id="color" type="color" label="Pick a Color" name="color" value="#EEEEEE" onchange="{! c.colorChanged }"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning:button aura:id="colorButton" label="Submit" disabled="true"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

and here is my controller... should be pretty straightforward.

```
({
    colorChanged: function(component, event, helper){
        var button = component.find('colorButton').getElement();
        button.set('v.disabled', false);
    },

})
```

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: you cannot access getElement for components. lightning:button is a component. if there was <button aura:id="colorButton"> then you will be able to do so. Locker service doesnot allow you to access you innerHtml of components.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use `getElement()` here because you're calling it on a component in another namespace (lightning).

For a component from your namespace, the framework will give you a [`secureComponent`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureComponent.js) instance, and for other namespaces, you'll get a [`secureComponentRef`](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureComponentRef.js) one. If you are curious, you can have a look to the implementations in the Aura framework to see which method is available for a `secureComponentRef`.

I think the easiest way to do what you want to achieve is to use an attribute that you'll pass to the `disabled` attribute of `lightning:button`:

**Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="buttonDisabled" type="Boolean" default="true"/>

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning:input aura:id="color" type="color" label="Pick a Color" name="color" value="#EEEEEE" onchange="{! c.colorChanged }"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <lightning:button aura:id="colorButton" label="Submit" disabled="{!v.buttonDisabled}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```
({
    colorChanged: function(component, event, helper){
        component.set('v.buttonDisabled', false);
    },  
})
```